# Regular expression prevent non English letters from email

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, validation

In our project, we use this regular expression to validate emails:

`"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,7}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"`

But it allows non English characters.

For example:

"مستخدم@mail.com"

"userمحمد@mail.com"

"userName@خادم.com"

are valid emails.

How to add another rule to this expression to limit inputs to English letters only?

Comment: email regexes are not fun for anybody involved. I would just use html validation for type=email possibly alongside some custom javascript using the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation) on the front end. Then on the C# side use the [MailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-7.0) class. That's a good first-line of defense, but you probably want to engage in [semantic validation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html#semantic-validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the alternation `|` in your pattern, and there is an optional closing bracket `\]?` which I think you don't need in an email address.

This part in the regex with Javascript and C# `[\w-\.]` does not seem to be a valid range in a character.

Instead of using `\w` you can use `[A-Za-z0-9]` to match ASCII chars and digits 0-9 in C#.

If you don't want to match consecutive dots or hyphens, you can use a pattern like this and then extend it if you have more characters that you want to allow:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndMcdE/1)

Note that this only validates an email address of this format.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot. It only misses "underscore". "^[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?:[.-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}$"

Comment: @Dr.MAF In that case you can change `[A-Za-z0-9]` to `\w`

Comment: I just added it in the range.

Comment: I just wonder how I can enforce letters in each segment. For now 3333@555.com is valid, which it shouldn't be the case, I think.

Comment: Can you help me with this issue? @Thefourthbird

Comment: @Dr.MAF Instead of using `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` to allow only digits as well, you can write it like this `[_0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*` to match at least a single char A-Za-z like this https://regex101.com/r/QQUxIi/1 and then you can also do that for the second part.

Comment: Thank you. This did the job. @The fourth bird

Answer (score 0):

Can do like this

```
        string[] StrInputNumber = { "pradeep1234@yahoo.in", "مستخدم@mail.com'", "userمحمد@mail.com", "userName@خادم.com" };
        Regex ASCIILettersOnly = new Regex(@"^[\P{L}A-Za-z]*$");
        foreach (String item in StrInputNumber) {
        if (ASCIILettersOnly.IsMatch(item)) {
         Console.WriteLine(item + " ==> valid");
        }
        else {
         Console.WriteLine(item + " ==>not valid");
        }
        }
```

**Output**

[image]

for some basic explanation about regex [Click Here](https://blog.xisb.de/2012/05/what-absolutely-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this website](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expression

If you don't need to keep your current expression you can use this one instead:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$.
```

I tested it with your examples and it works as you want.